# When Renaming Folders Using CSV, is there a Way to Break Out of Loop Early When Hit Occurs?

Tags: powershell, loops, csv, directory

I have a script that is working swimmingly but due to the sheer volume of folders it evaluates it's evaluating each conditional across all nested subfolders four levels down (per the script's starting point). Since only one hit can occur due to the specifics of what is being evaluated, if a hit occurs say 1,000 folders in, is it possible to stop evaluating further and move to the next record evaluation?

Script below, insights are appreciated.

```
# Assume the CSV is 100,000 entries and that Column3 contains a snippet of alphanumeric text
# that is grabbed using a split, then the file server is searched for a matching subfolder
# four levels down and renamed with a different snippet of alphanumeric text from Column1.

$folderPath = "Z:\TopLevelFolder\*\*\*\*"
$csvPath = "C:\PathToCSV\file.csv"
$count = 0

$csvData = Import-Csv -Path $csvPath

foreach ($row in $csvData)
{
    $prefix = ($row.Column3 -split ' - ')[0]
    $prepend = ($row.Column1 -split '-')[-1]
    $subfolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders)
    {
        if ($subfolder.Name -like "*$prefix*")
        {
            $newName = "("+ $prepend + ") " + $subfolder.Name
            Rename-Item -Path $subfolder.FullName -NewName $newName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            $count++
            Write-Host $subfolder.FullName
        }
    }
}
Write-Host $count.ToString() "folders renamed"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `break` statement to exit a loop early.

For example

```
Foreach(I in coll){
    If (condition) {
        # do stuff
        break
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_break?view=powershell-7.4)

Comment: I did try adding a break statement to the if ($subfolder.Name ... ) block but that doesn't do anything to speed things up. Have any insights about how that might look or work in the context of my script?

Comment: You should profile your code to find where the delay is. Get-ChildItem can be very slow if you have large numbers of sub folders. One way I e found to improve speed is to use Get-ChildItem to deal with the files at the current level, then use it again to get a list of sub folders, and recurse down the tree. Limiting the number of items it's dealing with seems to help.

Comment: Have an example of what that might look like in the context of my script? I'm behind the magic 8-ball for a task to be completed such that deep dive learning and trial and error is a luxury for tomorrow.

Comment: That's a different question. I've answered the question you asked here. If you want to ask about recursing folders in Powershell, post a new question.